# Redirect people to website

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I'm trying to figure out how I can redirect all traffic on a certain domain to my other website, based on the referrer.

For example, we only want people with no referrer, or linked to from our other website, to be able to access the site.

I was thinking of a script that would redirect everyone to a website of my choice, if their referrer didn't match the site I specify (but still allowed no referrer traffic).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: FYI, referrer is easily forged.

Comment: @sberry Agreed - the referer header is never to be trusted. A lot of anti-virus software strips this header from all requests also so it's not reliable even when non-hostile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following PHP code should do it (but remember, this cannot be used as a security measure, since the `Referer` header is provided by the client):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) &&
    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] &&
    stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "example.org") === false) {
    header("Location: http://example.com/", true, 302);
    exit();
}
```

Here we check that the client provided the `Referer` header, next that it is non-empty, and finally that it lacks the proper domain name (here "example.org"). If so, we redirect the client to another URL (here "http://example.com/") and exit.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the HTTP referer (intentional misspelling) header:

```
if (!stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "somesiteyouspecify") && !$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == '') ... redirect
```

Answer (score 1):

you should configure that as RewriteRules in the webserver like Apache or nginx. Examples can be found easily in the documentation ... (I would give one, if I knew the used webserver software ...)